# How do I get a list of key, value pairs from the database for a select list in Yii?

Tags: php, yii2

How do I get a list of key/value pairs to populate the options to a relation in a select list in Yii?

Similar to the following in Rails:

```
= f.select :age_group_id, AgeGroup.order(:name).pluck(:name, :id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the list of values, perhaps in the controller

```
$campaigns = Campaign::find()->select('name')->indexBy('id')->column();
```

Display the list

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'campaign_id')->dropDownList($campaigns) ?>
```

Comment: key is not right its not set as key but the position in array

Answer (score 0):

Could  be useful somethings like his

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'your_field')->listBox( ArrayHelper::map(Country::find()->all(), 'country_id', 'Country_description'),['prompt'=>'']) ?>
```

or for dropdown

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'your_field')->dropDownList( ArrayHelper::map(Country::find()->all(), 'country_id', 'Country_description'),['prompt'=>'']) ?>
```

change country_id, your_field and country_description for your need